# how to which function is being executed by worker thread(events/0)

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, scheduling, linuxthreads

For debugging purposes, I like to know which function is executed by worker thread(events/#0).  Is there any way I get this information when the evnets executes ?

Comment: Add logging to the functions?

Comment: logging to which function ? work queue is used by so many process. how can i add logging to each function, as there may be so many and i dont know when a function is going to run. That is why i asked, if there is any why to know what work is currently done by worker thread.

Comment: Why cant you add logging to every function - it is your source code right. There cannot be that many functions - does not each thread call the same function (add the thread id to the logging result)